# Microsoft graph api getOffice365ActivationsUserCounts return expected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 from C# [getoffice365activationsusercounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activationsusercounts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
Its return error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I am using following code in C#

```
 try
   {
      Graph::GraphServiceClient graphClient1 = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { "Reports.Read.All" });
      var report = await graphClient1.Reports.GetOffice365ActivationsUserCounts().Request().GetAsync();
    }
catch (System.Exception ex)  { throw ex; }
```

```
     private Graph::GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string[] scopes)
     {
       return GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
       {
         string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(scopes);
         return result;
        }, webOptions.GraphApiUrl); 
      }
```

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a *bug* with [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), the exception occurs while de-serializing response payload from [`getOffice365ActivationsUserCounts` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activationsusercounts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

Until the bug is resolved, the request could be executed like this:

```
var message = graphClient.Reports.GetOffice365ActivationsUserCounts().Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message); 
// Download report data
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```